# Will this High Frequency AC Signal Generator Circuit work?

Tags: ac, dc, frequency, inverter

I am going to make a variable DC to AC (10-100kHz). The circuit controlled by 2 PWM Signal from microcontroller to drive NMosfet connected to pull signal from two  Ferrite core Transformer primary coil end which the CT connected to 3.3V. Here is the circuit 
[image]

I simulated the circuit in Eagle, CircuitLab, and MultiSim. The circuit works great on MultiSim, sometimes work on CircuitLab, but it wont work on Eagle. Which makes me a bit hesitant.

What do you think about the circuit? will it work?
I am using [[78253/35JC][2](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/281/kmp_78253j-53182.pdf)](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/281/kmp_78253j-53182.pdf) for the transformer.

Thank you

Comment: Have you computed the voltage integral for the lowest frequency & max PWM rate?

Comment: BTW: 10-100kHz is not HF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a push-pull configuration. I assume, you will turn: on positive->off positive->dead time->on negative->dead time-> ...repeat.

At 10kHZ with duty ratio 50:50, ommiting the dead time you get a voltage integral of 165uVs for each half cycle. So too big for a transformer that accepts 30uVS. You may not be able to work at lower frequency.